# Show that $3x^5-4x^3-6x^2+6$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Can’t seem to apply Eisenstein’s criterion. It doesn’t make sense to reduce modulo 2 since the constant term disappears… What are some other possible strategies to apply here?

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion for p=2 is perfectly applicable here.

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion will show that ther are no rational roots so you can eliminate the possibility that the polynomial has a linear factor but you must also eliminate the possibility that the polynomial factors into an irreducible quadratic times an irreducible cubic.

Comment: @P.Lawrence Eisenstein's criterion (with $p=2$) directly shows it is irreducible, not just that there are no linear factors.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, and so I will leave an answer.

V.Ch. is correct, the Eisenstein criterion will give you irreducibility. We apply the criterion with the prime $2$ because it divides every coefficient and doesn't divide the constant coefficient more than once.

From your question it seems that perhaps you do not know the Eisenstein criterion. In this case, another method is to reduce modulo $5$. If $\alpha$ is a root of $3x^5 - 4x^3 - 6x^2 + 6 \equiv 3x^5 + x^3 - x^2 + 1 \; (\textrm{mod } 5)$ then since $\alpha^5 \equiv \alpha \; (\textrm{mod } 5)$, we have $\alpha^3 - \alpha^2 + 3\alpha + 1 \equiv 0 \; (\textrm{mod } 5)$. You can verify that the polynomial $x^3 - x^2 + 3x + 1$ has no roots by plugging in integers modulo $5$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Your answers led me to search Eisenstein’s criterion online. I realized my professor gave a restrictive version in class — he stated it for monic polynomials only (not sure why), which is why I thought it was not applicable here.

Comment: @user523692 Actually if you want to apply Eisenstein with a prime $p$ to a polynomial, then you do need $p$ not dividing the highest degree coefficient. Monic polynomials have the advantage of avoiding this minor problem. You probably have seen this already, but you can find it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion .